# php, send email from any email address

Tags: php, email

Email will be delivered to people - a veryusual thing.

But the address from which the email will be sent will vary from time to time. And the address from which the mail will be sent will be taken as an input from the site admin.

The thing is, to send email from a gmail account needs a certain type of coding, to do it with yahoo needs another kind of coding and so on.

What is the way in php to send emails from any email address?

Is there any such script available for free ?

Comment: Your code/script will remain the same independent of your from email address so not to worry about it...

Comment: to use a gmail address, u need the smpt. Other email providers have their own rule i think... Think about phpMailer, a famous mailing script, only mail_to function is not fullfledged i think for security (?) or other things.. am i right?

Comment: May I suggest that you also read this: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/04/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code.html

Comment: @Klaus-Byskov-Hoffmann, full with jargon.. can u do a favor .. putting just the gist here?

Comment: May I have an explanation of the -ve rating please?

Comment: The gist: If you want to make sure that the emails always arrive, there is no feasible way to do what you are set out to do. Why? Because unless you take the correct measures your emails will end up in a spam folder. And how are you going to take the correct measures when you don't know which sender address you will be using? If you only allowed certain sender domains, you could definitely succeed, but you are asking for a way to send from **any** address. In short, you ***cannot*** send from any domain without a lot of your mails being blocked by spam filters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sending email without authentication

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@whateverdomain.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@whateverdomain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@whateverdomain.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

The correct way of sending email is through a SMTP connection.
Assuming the [PEAR Mail package](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail) is installed.

```
<?php
 require_once "Mail.php";

 $from = "Name Surname <sender@yourdomain.com>";
 $to = "Name Whatever <recipient@example.com>";
 $subject = "Subject!";
 $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

 $host = "mail.yourdomain.com";
 $username = "smtp_username";
 $password = "smtp_password";

 $headers = array ('From' => $from,
   'To' => $to,
   'Subject' => $subject);
 $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
   array ('host' => $host,
     'auth' => true,
     'username' => $username,
     'password' => $password));

 $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

 if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
   echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
  }
 ?>
```

Assuming you have Zend Framework, you can do the same by sending through [Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.html) over SMTP. The example below uses information on Google SMTP

```
require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php'; //Should be in the include_path
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();

$config = array('ssl' => 'tls', 'port' => 587, 'auth' => 'login', 'username' => 'username@gmail.com', 'password' => 'password');
$transport = new Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp('smtp.gmail.com', $config);

$mail = new Zend_Mail();
if (strtolower($this->getType()) == 'html')
$mail->setBodyHtml($this->getBody());
}
else {
$mail->setBodyText($this->getBody());
}

$mail
->setFrom($this->getFromEmail(), $this->getFromName())
->addTo($this->getToEmail(), $this->getToName())
->setSubject($this->getSubject());

$mail->send($transport);
```

Comment: does the first approach ensure to deliver emails just as the 2nd approaxh do?

Comment: Ensure!?
The methods above deliver an email. The method the email is send are different. The first methods uses a sendmail or similar service from the OS.
The 2nd and 3d approach send email via SMTP. They are less likely to be marked as SPAM (assuming SPF records are correct for the server IP as well) in comparison to the first attempt.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you set your mail headers which are containing, who is sending that email address. Fortunately, this mostly will arrive as spam (keywords: SPF, DNS PTR, ...)

Easiest thing would be to create classes for every account you are going to use (gmail, yahoo, ...) and then use the factory pattern to keep your code clean.

> http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php

Best option would be: Use smtp with authentication. This is the most supported standard and you only have to code solutions for services that don't provide smtp auth.

**UPDATE**

I don't know how to help you. You want to send mails from every domain, without them being flagged as spam, just by providing a "mail from (enter email address here)" input field, and a full-magic-do-it-everything-script-package. But without having an idea of how mailing works.

Pro tip: read about SMTP and get an idea of how sending mails is working.

Comment: any ready made script would be most welcome

Comment: I'd append one if I'd know one

Comment: so many email providers r there. Also web mails are to be taken into consideration

Comment: updated. use smtp. and code for services that doesn't provide smtp.

Comment: for how many services should I do that? how can i know all of those services? any ready made script?

Comment: SMTP is what every basic ISP uses that provides email to his users, so it can't be that hard to use it. If you want to send via smtp, use the PEAR SMTP package (see http://pear.php.net/package/Net_SMTP/redirected). "For how many services should i do that?" - probably for every service not supporting smtp, which is a very small amount..

Comment: i dont know much about it . i want to use the easiest way for a sure delivery. the email address will be taken just in an html input box. And then the address wil be used

Comment: smtp addresses r  different for different emails. right? web mails r also to be considered. So do I need an exclusive list of all the email service providers?

Comment: And that's not possible (ever heard of spam? everyone can send mails as everyone? really?). If you don't know about smtp, read about it. You don't need to know much of it, but a basic grasp to use it.

Comment: "So do I need an exclusive list of all the email service providers?" No, you need your user to provide this server, and add username / password to authenticate to this server.

Comment: so besides asking for the sender email from the admin, the smtp info should also be asked?

Comment: YES, that's what I wrote. Please, read about those topics and ask specific questions. This is horrible.