# Possibility of sending an email from any sender in PHP

Tags: php, email

When I was working on my website, I was sending an email to myself from the PHP code of my website. The code for sending it was something like this:

```php
<?php 
$to = "myemail@gmail.com";
$subject = "Test email";
$message = "This is a test email";
$headers = "From: info@mydomain.com";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

But in the headers, I accidentally misspelled the from email-address. To my surprise, it did send an email to me when I checked my inbox, but with a typo in the from part. Then I tried changing the from address to a different existing email of mine, that should not be accessible by my website. But to my surprise, it still sent the email to me and also with the from address of my other email address.

My question is: wouldn’t this be a serious security vulnerability? Since I can send an email from any address without logging into them. With that, I could impersonate anyone.

PS: I am not that familiar with how email works, so this may be an easy question. I am also guessing that this is possible in any way where you can set the headers yourself, I just found it in PHP.

Comment: the smtp server is yours?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php, send email from any email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8910508/php-send-email-from-any-email-address)

Comment: _"wouldn’t this be a serious security vulnerability"_ Yep, this is how email works. There is no inherent sender validation. Add-ons like SPF and DKIM have improved this, but they are not generally required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called email spoofing. Emails are send with the SMTP (Smart Mail Transfer Protocol) and it is possible to send emails via SMTP without verification that you actually are the owner of this email address. This is not a new trick and that is why you always have to be suspicious. After my knowledge, these emails are normally accepted by the receiving server but they keep logs of the incoming SMTPs, so they save the senders IP address. I do not recommend to use email spoofing for malicious purposes. Have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_spoofing) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, now I am a little more familiar with email and smtp :)